# Inserting small vectors into a larger one

Tags: matlab, vector

Let's say we have a "Dirac comb" which gives the beginning positions of some "pattern":

```
N_pattern = 5; pattern = rand(1,N_pattern); 
N = 100;  dirac_comb =  zeros(1, N);  
idx = [1 20 50 80];           % let's say we want four occurrences of the pattern inside the final_vector
dirac_comb (idx) = 1;         % let's say this the comb with the positions of patterns
```

All I want to do is to insert the "pattern" vector on the positions indicated by the Dirac comb. Normally, this may be done by a convolution:

```
final_vector = conv(dirac_comb, pattern);
```

I don't want to use the convolution because I use very large vectors and thus it is very slow. The presence of the Dirac comb in this problem is a little bit forced, the `idx` variable might be enough to solve this problem.

**First question:** how to insert the "pattern" in the `final_vect` at the positions indicated by `idx`, in a vectorized way.

**Second question:** let's say we randomized the positions `idx` of the patterns, so there is a possibility that two patterns may intersect. If this would happen, I have to sum up these two patterns (the region of intersection).

```
idx = randi([1 N-N_pattern],[1, 8]); % lets' say we have 8 occurrences
```

Should it be possible to take into account this summation, yet in a vectorized manner?

Comment: Regarding the second question: this is far from trivial, isn't it? If you have in your Dirac comb two adjacent `1`s, you'll just get the pattern twice next to each other. In order to have overlaps, you have to include the patterns one by one, so you have to generate each new `idx` for the expanded, partially processed `final_vector`. Isn't this right?

Comment: If I understood the question of @andras, the problem is to include patterns all at once.

Answer (score 1):

To insert the pattern into `final_vector` without using `conv()` you can use replication and indexing in MATLAB.

First you'll need to augment `idx` so that instead of it containing the starting elements of the ranges where it should place `pattern` it contains all of the indices. We can accomplish this using [`bsxfun()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) (as pointed out by @[Andras Deak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067311/andras-deak))

```
>> idx = [1 20 50 80];
>> indexes = bsxfun(@plus,idx',0:N_pattern-1)
indexes =

     1     2     3     4     5
    20    21    22    23    24
    50    51    52    53    54
    80    81    82    83    84
```

then you can insert `pattern` into `final_vector` by indexing the vector with `idx` and replicating `pattern` with either [`repmat()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) or [`bsxfun()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) (again pointed out by @[Andras Deak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067311/andras-deak)) to fit in those indexes

```
>> final_vector = zeros(1, length(dirac_comb) + length(pattern) - 1);
>> final_vector(indexes) = repmat(pattern, size(indexes, 1), 1);
```

or

```
>> final_vector = zeros(1, length(dirac_comb) + length(pattern) - 1);
>> final_vector(indexes) = bsxfun(@plus, pattern, zeros(numel(idx), 1));
```

---

Just a point to note which I didn't think previously needed mentioning. [`conv()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) produces a vector of length `length(dirac_comb) + length(pattern) - 1`. To produce the same length as [`conv()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) `final_vector` should be allocated with `final_vector = zeros(1, length(dirac_comb) + length(pattern) - 1);`.

Comment: If I may suggest:  `bsxfun(@plus,idx',0:N_pattern-1)` will take care of the index matrix:) And I'd advise against `length` in this context: what if there are more inclusions than pattern length? Suggest `size(idx,2)` instead.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks! I was trying a `bsxfun` solution first but I'm not too adepth with it yet.

Comment: Also, the second repmat can be done away with `bsxfun(@plus,pattern,zeros(length(idx0),1))`, if you keep the original vector `idx` as `idx0`. Probably it's most logical to define `N_spikes` or something at the beginning, from the length of the original `idx`. But this is up to OP. **Edit**: I just realized the original `numel/length` is exactly `size(idx,1)`:)

Comment: I'll really have to start looking at `bsxfun` properly. That makes for a much better solution than what I previously had. Thanks @AndrasDeak!

Comment: No problem. To be honest, the repmat version is always more transparent. But efficiency ftw, right?;)

Comment: interesting moment - different methods gives different `final_vector` size:
`conv -> 1x104`

`repmat -> 1x100`

`bsxfun -> 1x84`

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Both `repmat` and `bsxfun` give a `1x84` unless you use `final_vector = zeros(1, N);`. `conv` produces a vector of length `length(dirac_comb) + length(pattern) - 1`. I didn't think this needed mentioning but I've added a note on it to the answer.

Comment: So if the sizes are the same, will the output vectors also be the same? And then there's question 2: with the current implementation, patterns will overwrite each other rather than summing up. I think this can be `bsxfun`ned as well.

Comment: I checked all methods - all positions of all `patterns` in `final_vector` are right. BUT I've been written this comment about overwriting but @Andras Deak was the first - there is no summation of patterns

Comment: The problem is partially resolved but still there is a problem when the comb is supposed to be  [1 20 20 50 80]. I was thinking also of using the bsxfun